# .NET: Difference between PasswordDeriveBytes and Rfc2898DeriveBytes

Tags: c#, .net, pbkdf2, pkcs#5

I'm trying to understand some C#-code, I have been handed, which deals with cryptography, and specifically uses `PasswordDeriveBytes` from `System.Security.Cryptography`.

In the [.NET docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.passwordderivebytes.aspx) , it says that `PasswordDeriveBytes` uses "an extension of the PBKDF1 algorithm" which is later in the document specified as "the PKCS#5 v2.0 standard", which is PBKDF2 (as far as I can tell). Everywhere on the net I've found (including here on Stack Exchange), though, everyone says "use Rfc2898DeriveBytes, cause Password* is deprecated and uses PBKDF1". But the only difference in the docs at [msdn.microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com) seems to be that the Rfc*-version specifically mentions PBKDF2, where Password* says "extension of PBKDF1" and "PKCS#5 v 2.0".

So, can anyone tell me what the difference is between the two classes (if any) and why I should use one rather than the other for PBKDF2 password key derivation?

Now, other code, that deals with the same data, explicitly uses PBKDF2, and works, so that would suggest that indeed `PasswordDeriveBytes` also uses PBKDF2, or that PBKDF2 is simply compatible with PBKDF1 under certain circumstances, but I want to know for sure that it's not some side effect of some random thing, and that things just magically works (and eventually probably will magically and spectacularly break) without anyone really understanding why.

Answer (score 3):

If you instantiate `PasswordDeriveBytes` and make a single call to the `GetBytes` method passing a value which is smaller than the output size of the underlying digest algorithm then you get back a value from the [PBKDF1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898#section-5.1) algorithm.

If you make two calls to GetBytes for the same object you may encounter a counting bug in the implementation.

PBKDF1 is only described to output up to the size of the hash algorithm (e.g. 20 bytes for SHA-1), but the PasswordDeriveBytes class has made up a formula to support up to 1000 times the hash output size.  So a large value produced by this class may not be easily attainable in another platform.

---

If you instantiate `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` you get a streaming implementation of the [PBKDF2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898#section-5.2) algorithm. The most obvious difference of PBKDF2 over PBKDF1 is that PBKDF2 allows the generation of an arbitrary amount of data (the limit is `(2^32-1)*hashOutputSize`; or for SHA-1 85,899,345,900 bytes).  PBKDF2 also uses a more complex construction (in particular, HMAC over direct digest) to make recovering the input password from an output value more difficult.

The "streaming" in the implementation is that the concatenation of `GetBytes(5)` and `GetBytes(3)` is the same as `GetBytes(8)`. Unlike in PasswordDeriveBytes, this works correctly in Rfc2898DeriveBytes.

---

PBKDF1 was originally created to generate DES keys, published in [PKCS #5 v1.5](ftp://ftp.rsasecurity.com/pub/pkcs/ascii/pkcs-5.asc) in 1993.
PBKDF2 was published in PKCS #5 v2.0 (which was republished as [RFC2898](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898)) in 1999. A slide deck which should be found at ftp://ftp.rsasecurity.com/pub/pkcs/pkcs-5v2/pkcs5v2-0.pdf (but seems to be having issues so ftp://ftp.dfn-cert.de/pub/pca/docs/PKCS/ftp.rsa.com/99workshop/pkcs5_v2.0.ppt may hve to do) further summarizes differences. (The slide deck was written by RSA Security, the creators of PBKDF1 and PBKDF2, and they are the people who recommend PBKDF2 over PBKDF1).

Answer (score 2):

I think a great answer to this would be found here:

[C# PasswordDeriveBytes Confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9231754/c-sharp-passwordderivebytes-confusion)

But to sumup:

Microsoft's implementation of original PKCS#5 (aka PBKDF1) include insecure extensions to provide more bytes than the hash function can provide (see bug reports here and here).

Even if it was not buggy you should avoid undocumented, proprietary extensions to standards (or you might never be able to decrypt your data in the future - at least not outside Windows.)

I strongly suggest you to use the newer Rfc2898DeriveBytes which implements PBKDF2 (PKCS#5 v2) which is available since .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a blog post detailing the differences:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2004/04/14/generating-a-key-from-a-password.aspx

PBKDF2 can be used to generate keys of any length, which is very useful for password-based **encryption** (it can generate any key length as required by the symmetric cipher) but means less for secure password storage. It also applies the salt using HMAC instead of concatenation like PBKDF1, which has better security properties in cases of weak salts.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't asking about the difference between 1 and 2, but the difference between two particular .NET classes. :)

Comment: One of which implements 1, while the other implements 2 :)

Comment: So what are the "Extensions"?

Answer (score 0):

[PKCS#5 v2.0](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2898.txt) defines both PBKDF1 and PBKDF2, the former for reasons of backwards compatibility and *also* recommends you use PBKDF2 for new applications. I've no idea why the latter is better than the former, but the two .NET classes do seem to use different but interoperable algorithms. (Possibly because only the resulting key is being exchanged, not the inputs + KDF.)

Comment: Not necessarily, you could still be including which encryption scheme / KDF is used by the output data and the "other code" you mention is a code path used after it's been determined the encryption scheme uses PBKDF2. Can't really tell just from "explicitly uses PBKDF2".