# C# PasswordDeriveBytes Confusion

Tags: c#, cryptography, pbkdf2

I have following code in C#

```
PasswordDeriveBytes DerivedPassword = new PasswordDeriveBytes(Password, SaltValueBytes, HashAlgorithm, PasswordIterations);
byte[] KeyBytes = DerivedPassword.GetBytes(32);
```

I am using "SHA1" hashing algorithm.

According to SHA1 definition, its generate 160 bits (20 bytes) key. My question is how GetBytes method get 32 bytes from DerivedPassword, what algorithm used behind GetBytes method?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Microsoft's implementation of original PKCS#5 (aka PBKDF1) include **insecure** extensions to provide more bytes than the hash function can provide (see bug reports [here](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=316364) and [here](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=372893)).

Even if it was not buggy you should avoid undocumented, proprietary extensions to standards (or you might never be able to decrypt your data in the future - at least not outside Windows.)

I **strongly** suggest you to use the newer `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` which implements PBKDF2 (PKCS#5 v2) which is available since .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 5):

> what algorithm used behind GetBytes method?

It uses the algorithm PBKDF1, which is slightly modified to allow arbitrary key length. A replacement class, [`Rfc2898DeriveBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx) uses PBKDF2.

You can read the [Wikipedia Article on PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) for a general idea of what underlying concepts are making this work.

Comment: How this method derived 32 bytes from 20 bytes (which 'SHA1' hashing algorithm generated).

Comment: @Siddiqui @`HenrickHellstrom explained it nicely.

Answer (score 4):

The key derivation function uses a feature called **Key Stretching**. (Don't bother looking it up on Wikipedia, because the current article confuses the concept with Key Strengthening, which is something completely different.)

Key stretching is commonly done by applying a PRF (such as a hash function or a cipher) in either CTR mode, or by iterating it and concatenating the intermediate outputs.

For instance, if you use the CTR procedure, SHA-1 as PRF, and want 32 bytes of pseudo random output, you concatenate SHA1(keymaterial,0) with the first 12 bytes of SHA1(keymaterial,1).

Comment: thanks for your replay, can you give me little more explanation about CTR procedure.

Comment: In this case, the numbers 0 and 1 could be represented by a single bit (remember SHA-1 operates on strings of bits as input), but usually (keymaterial,0) etc is defined as e.g. (a) keymaterial with a single byte (or word) 0 appended at the end, or (b) a full 64 byte input block with keymaterial first, some padding (usually bytes with value zero), and a single byte with value 0 at the end.

Comment: I have this 
PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes( passPhrase,new byte[0],"SHA1",1);
byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(32);
according to your answer is it python code do the same  
hash_key1 = PBKDF1(key.encode(), bytearray(8), 20, count=1, hashAlgo=SHA1)
hash_key2 = PBKDF1(key.encode(), bytearray(8), 12, count=2, hashAlgo=SHA1)
keyBytes = hash_key1 + hash_key2 @HenrickHellström